# Search a delimited string in a file - Python

Tags: python, text

I have the following read.json file

```
{:{"JOL":"EuXaqHIbfEDyvph%2BMHPdCOJWMDPD%2BGG2xf0u0mP9Vb4YMFr6v5TJzWlSqq6VL0hXy07VDkWHHcq3At0SKVUrRA7shgTvmKVbjhEazRqHpvs%3D-%1E2D%TL/xs23EWsc40fWD.tr","LAPTOP":"error"}
```

and python script :

```
import re

shakes = open("read.json", "r")
needed = open("needed.txt", "w")
for text in shakes:
    if re.search('JOL":"(.+?).tr', text):
         print >> needed, text,
```

I want it to find what's between two words (JOL":" and .tr) and then print it. But all it does is printing all the text set in "read.json".

Comment: First, that's not a JSON file; you can't have a `:` all by itself, only between a key and a value inside an object.

Comment: Second, if it actually _were_ a JSON file, why would you try to parse that with `re` instead of just using `json.load`?

Comment: It's juste an example, let's consider it as text file, will that be ok ?

Comment: Knowing what format your data are in is important. Using regular expressions to parse non-regular languages is a bad idea. Even using regular expressions to parse regular languages can be a bad idea if there's a pre-written, pre-debugger, pre-optimized parser already available. Sometimes it's still worth slapping a regex together as a quick hack because you can do it in a few seconds and using the right parser would take longer, but if you can't get it working and have to go ask other people for help, that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `re.search`, but you're not doing anything with the returned match, except to check that there is one. Instead, you're just printing out the original `text`. So of course you get the whole line.

The solution is simple: just store the result of `re.search` in a variable, so you can use it. For example:

```
for text in shakes:
    match = re.search('JOL":"(.+?).tr', text)
    if match:
        print >> needed, match.group(1)
```

In your example, the match is `JOL":"EuXaqHIbfEDyvph%2BMHPdCOJWMDPD%2BGG2xf0u0mP9Vb4YMFr6v5TJzWlSqq6VL0hXy07VDkWHHcq3At0SKVUrRA7shgTvmKVbjhEazRqHpvs%3D-%1E2D%TL/xs23EWsc40fWD.tr`, and the first (and only) group in it is `EuXaqHIbfEDyvph%2BMHPdCOJWMDPD%2BGG2xf0u0mP9Vb4YMFr6v5TJzWlSqq6VL0hXy07VDkWHHcq3At0SKVUrRA7shgTvmKVbjhEazRqHpvs%3D-%1E2D%TL/xs23EWsc40fWD`, which is (I think) what you're looking for.

However, a couple of side notes:

First, `.` is a special pattern in a regex, so you're actually matching anything up to *any character* followed by `tr`, not `.tr`. For that, escape the `.` with a `\`. (And, once you start putting backslashes into a regex, use a raw string literal.) So: `r'JOL":"(.+?)\.tr'`.

Second, this is making a lot of assumptions about the data that probably aren't warranted. What you really want here is not "everything between `JOL":"` and `.tr`", it's "the value associated with key `'JOL'` in the JSON object". The only problem is that this isn't quite a JSON object, because of that prefixed `:`. Hopefully you know where you got the data from, and therefore what format it's actually in. For example, if you know it's actually a sequence of colon-prefixed JSON objects, the right way to parse it is:

```
d = json.loads(text[1:])
if 'JOL' in d:
    print >> needed, d['JOL']
```

Finally, you don't actually have anything named `needed` in your code; you opened a file named `'needed.txt'`, but you called the file object `love`. If your real code has a similar bug, it's possible that you're overwriting some completely different file over and over, and then looking in `needed.txt` and seeing nothing changed each time…

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your starting and ending matching strings only appear once, you can ignore that it's JSON. If that's OK, then you can split on the starting characters (JOL":"), take the 2nd element of the split array [1], then split again on the ending characters (.tr) and take the 1st element of the split array [0].

```
>>> text = '{:{"JOL":"EuXaqHIbfEDyvph%2BMHPdCOJWMDPD%2BGG2xf0u0mP9Vb4YMFr6v5TJzWlSqq6VL0hXy07VDkWHHcq3At0SKVUrRA7shgTvmKVbjhEazRqHpvs%3D-%1E2D%TL/xs23EWsc40fWD.tr","LAPTOP":"error"}'

>>> text.split('JOL":"')[1].split('.tr')[0]

'EuXaqHIbfEDyvph%2BMHPdCOJWMDPD%2BGG2xf0u0mP9Vb4YMFr6v5TJzWlSqq6VL0hXy07VDkWHHcq3At0SKVUrRA7shgTvmKVbjhEazRqHpvs%3D-%1E2D%TL/xs23EWsc40fWD'
```